# How do I properly dispatch actions inside the React Lifecycle Methods?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, action, react-lifecycle

How do I properly dispatch actions in React Lifecycle Methods?

Hello, friends 
I have an action called `checkSession()` inside my very parent component (App.jsx). This action helps me to get user info. 
 
This is how App.jsx looks like:

```
class App extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.checkSession();
  }
  render() {
    if (this.props.auth === null) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    } else {
       return (
         <BrowserRouter>
           <Route path="/cart" component={Cart} />
         </BrowserRouter>
      );
    }
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = ({ auth }) => { auth };
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { checkSession })(App);
```

How do I properly dispatch another action inside the Cart.jsx component. 
I try to dispatch the action inside the `componentWillReceiveProps` methods but it creates an infinite loop. 
My Cart.jsx component looks like this:

```
import { getCart } from "../../actions"; 

class Cart extends Component {
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps, nextState) {
    if (nextProps.auth) {
      this.props.getCart(nextProps.auth.googleId);
    } else {
      this.props.getCart(null);
    }
  }
  render() {
    ......some staff  
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = ({ auth }) => { auth };
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getCart })(Cart);
```

I have just tried to dispatch this action inside the ComponentWillMount - but my props are not ready yet so I got an error. 
Help me please with any advice, and sorry for my English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you have to detect if the props have changed before firing the dispatch:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps, nextState) {
    const currentId = this.props.auth && this.props.auth.googleId;
    const nextId = nextProps.auth && nextProps.auth.googleId;
    if (currentId !== nextId) {
        this.props.getCart(nextProps.auth.googleId);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it working, but when I refresh page this action ` this.props.getCart(nextProps.auth.googleId)` won't be executed. And I can't use `componentWillMount` because of infinite loop. 
How can i deal with this?